# Tkinter not opening windows as expected

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a piece of code as below. Though its running fine but no matter whichever option number I enter (1 or 2 or 3 or 4), it opens the same window only titled "Employee Database". I want that if I enter 2 it should open "Attendance Register" and so on and so forth.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("multisoft")
title = Label(window, text="Multisoft", font=("Arial Bold", 30))
title.grid(column=250, row=0)
window.geometry("500x500")
emp_data = Label(window, text="1.Employee Database  ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
emp_data.grid(column=0, row=1)
atd_reg = Label(window, text="2.Attendance Register ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
atd_reg.grid(column=0, row=2)
pay = Label(window, text="3.Payment                   ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
pay.grid(column=0, row=3)
Quit = Label(window, text="4.Quit                           ", font=("Arial Bold", 10))
Quit.grid(column=0, row=4)
txt = Entry(window, width=25)
txt.grid(column=0, row=5)

def clicked():
    if txt.get() == 1 or "employee database":
        em_data = Tk()
        em_data.title("Employee Database")
        em_data.geometry("500x500")
        but.configure()
    elif txt.get() == 2 or "attendance register":
        at_reg = Tk()
        at_reg.title("Attendance Register")
        at_reg.geometry("500x500")
        but.configure()
    elif txt.get() == 3 or "payement":
        ment = Tk()
        ment.title("Payment")
        ment.geometry("500x500")
        but.configure()
    elif txt.get == 4 or "quit":
        window.destroy()
        but.configure()

but = Button(window, text="enter", command=clicked)
but.grid(column=1, row=5)
window.mainloop()
```

What mistake I am doing? Can anyone please point out? Please help as I am new to coding and creating GUI in python for the 1st time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

```
if txt.get() == 1 or "employee database":
```

The `==` has priority over `or`.
So this `if` statement is equal to `if (txt.get() == 1) or "employee database"`

`if "employee database"` is `True` because the string will always contain text. So it will only be the first condition that's run.

You can use `if Userinput == ("1" or "employee database")` or `if Userinput in ("1","employee database")` . To be totally sure, you should also revise other `elif` statement, too.

Comment: Also, `txt.get()` will always return a string, and a string will never be equal to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `clicked()` function you have incorrect if statements.
Because the `==` has a higher precedence than the `or` keyword.
Therefore the if statement will be evaluated as `if (txt.get() == 1) or "employee database"` and that is always True because the `"employee database"` string is not empty and `txt.get()` will also always return a string and therefore never equal to `1`, so the first condition will always be run because `"employee database" == True"`.

Instead you need to do if statements like this:

```
if (txt.get() == "1" or txt.get() == "employee database"):
    # And code follows here...
```

Comment: You should also mention that `txt.get()` will always return a string, so it will never be equal to the integer `1`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Yeah, and that is correct, as that was to demonstrate the correct use of `or` and `==` precedence.

Comment: haha..so cute,But OP want to show the window when user input `1` .